# Do - word choice

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Is the verb **do** correct in this sentence?

Tom had just arrived in the Maldives, and his first activity was a diving lesson. He was a little scared because he had never **done** it before; however, he decided to **do** it anyway.

Comment: I@m bnot sure if you intended _do_ to mean "dive" or "take a diving lesson". I certainly read the first _done_ as meaning "dive", but then I'm confused when I get to the second _do_.

Comment: It's possible, though _he had never dived before_ would be better. You could say _he decided to go anyway_ (meaning 'go to the lesson').

Comment: Both your uses of "do" are grammatically correct. We understand from context that the first "done" refers to diving, and the second to "take a diving lesson".